# How would I pass variables to a `@events.test_start.add_listener` function

Tags: python, locust

I'm trying to run load tests with locust but I need to run some API calls before I start spawning workers. I already pass my user credentials as environment variables but I don't want to have to hard-code the host within the locustfile. I'm ideally looking to have something that looks like

```py
@events.test_start.add_listener
def on_test_start(**kwargs):
    init(host, username, password)
```

Where `init` will take care of all of the initial API calls.

Comment: Hi! I dont understand what it is you are trying to do. Where should host/username/password come from? Do you or do you NOT want to hard code the host? That sentence in your question seems to contradict itself.

Comment: I just reread my post and realized that I mistyped. I have the host saved in a locust config file. My original question is if theres a way to specify arguments that will passed into '``on_test_start()``' and if not, where is host referenced so that I can pull it into my start function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter, `environment`, to the init function contains locust settings in the `parsed_options` dict. Try getting host from there.

Something like (untested)

```
@events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(environment, **kwargs):
    init(environment.parsed_options[”host”], ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, this has been helpful. I was getting an error saying that ```environment.parsed_args``` doen't exist, but ```environment``` does have a host variable that i can use

Comment: Cool. It was supposed to be parsed_options, i have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on Cyberwiz's answer so I post a new answer, hope you don't mind.

I'm trying to do something similar to what you want to do, but I cannot get host url by doing `environment.parsed_options["host"]` , I got an error message which said `'Namespace' object is not subscriptable`

Instead, I tried using `environment.host` and I got the host url successfully, hope this might help for those who meet the same problem as I did!

Reference: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#environment-class